# Getting every channel in a guild

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to get every channel in a discord guild, but it gives me an error message.

```
if (message.content.startsWith('!get-channels')) {
        
    message.guild.channels.forEach(channel => {
        
        console.log(channel)
    
    })
        
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
                message.guild.channels.forEach(channel => {
                                       ^

TypeError: message.guild.channels.forEach is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because since discord.js v12 you now need to access Guild Channels using their [`cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=cache), so your solution would be to use `message.guild.channels.cache.forEach()`